# Can we change the shade of blue on the new popups?

Tags: feature-request, design, error-message, popups

Recently the error and notification popups have been changed.  Some are red:

[image]

And some are blue(ish):

[image]

I think the red (salmon?) one is perfect, but the blue is awful bright.  It really hurts my eyes when it pops up.

Could we change it to a blue that's not quite so bright?  Maybe something like `#1559B3` or `#1A56D9`?

Comment: I like the blue a lot better than the red

Comment: I think its refreshing when something that vibrant pops up in the middle of a boring expanse of gray.

Comment: The blue looks sexy. Why does the first error get a period and not the second? Also, the "X" button looks awkwardly close to the end of the line. Needs a left margin. Can it be vertically centered too? *rambles on*

Comment: When has a period not been covered in red? As for the blue, there is no end to the sadness @ani

Comment: @animuson  I would uptick that, except I don't agree with the first sentance :P

Comment: Can the secondary "blue" color be a color that matches the color scheme of the site it is used on, it is quite jarring on Ask Ubuntu, where most of the colors are Orange.

Comment: On the left right/vertical centering, I understand a set to the top right if it's multi-line.  That looks right.  On a single line alert it should probably be squared/centered so left right and top bottom offset are the same.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing `position:relative; top:5px;` FTW :D

Comment: I agree with @Seth, the blue is the brightest thing on the page (and this is even more radical on some other SE sites.